# Identificar error "E/MediaPlayer: error" generado por VideoView

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando con un `VideoView` en un `Fragment` que reproduce una lista de canales IP. Quisiera saber si puedo identificar los errores que generan el `VideoView` como se ve en el Log:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de identificarlos o capturarlos para poder hacer alguna acción al momento de aparecer?

Así estoy utilizando el `VideoView`:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoViewTV);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

O si se puede evitar que se genere este `Alert` o que se cierre pasados unos segundos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Se podría compartir el url de tu video?

Comment: Es algo así: http://user:password@172.30.1.2:8585/stream/channelid/6857426985?ticket=9845H352175J359YM2485PU23U36T33Y52E2HTY579&profile=webtv-h264-aac-mpegts

Comment: Quiero saber si puedo identificar en un String o algo así, si se genera un error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una forma para poder capturarlos que esta descrito en los eventos aquí te dejo una  [documentación](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_Video_Playback_on_Android_using_the_VideoView_and_MediaController_Classes).

Agregando un listener en el VideoView puedes capturar cuando falla la carga del video y con el retornar true evitas el error que tiene por defecto del VideoView si lo dejas en false retorna el error por defecto.

```
            videoview.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió muy bien. Eres lo que necesitaba.